# May any sequence in a topological vector space be convergent to zero with some positive weight?

Tags: general-topology

My question is the following: If $X$ is a real Hausdorff topological vector space and $(x_n)_n$ is an arbitrarly sequence in $X$, does there exist a sequence $(\alpha_n)$ of positive numbers such that $\alpha_n x_n\to 0$ in $X$.

Thank you!

Comment: If there is a counterexample it is not first countable.

Comment: Thank you Jonas. I've been thinking of the product space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ but I find no counterexample.

Comment: The maximum may not exist as a real number, I mean it could be $+\infty$, becuase the varible $m$ is real, not natural. Anyway I think I found a counterexample.

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry for some reason I misthought/read what space you're talking about!  I'll delete my wrong & irrelevant comment.

Comment: The counterexample is the following: Let $Y=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ the space of all sequences and $X=\mathbb{R}^Y$ the space of functions from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and define $x_n\in X$ as $x_n((\alpha_i)_i)=\alpha_i^{-1}$ if $\alpha_i>0$ else as $0$. Then for this sequence $x_n$ and any sequence of positive real numbers $(\alpha_i)_i$ we have that $\alpha_n x_n((\alpha_i)_i)=\alpha_n\alpha_n^{-1}=1$ so that in the coordinate $(\alpha_i)_i$, $x_n$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $X$ be the topological vector space space of all real-valued functions on $\Bbb R$, with the topology of pointwise convergence. (In other words, $X$ is the product of $|\Bbb R|$ copies of $\Bbb R$.) Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all strictly increasing sequences of positive integers; $|\Sigma|=|\Bbb R|$, so we can index $\Sigma$ as $\Sigma=\{\sigma_x:x\in\Bbb R\}$, where $\sigma_x=\langle\sigma_x(k):k\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\sigma_x(n)\;;$$

clearly $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $X$. Suppose that $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of positive real numbers. Then there is an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$\sigma_x(n)=\left\lceil\frac1{\alpha_n}\right\rceil$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so that $\alpha_nf_n(x)\ge 1$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and $\langle\alpha_nf_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to the zero function in $X$.